# Parsing time in Golang

Tags: go

I'm trying to create a Time struct based on some input called dateAdded. My code is like this:

```
dateAdded := "November 25, 2016"
layout := "September 9, 2016"
t, err := time.Parse(layout, dateAdded)
if err != nil {
    fmt.Println(err)
} else {
    fmt.Println(t)
}
```

And I get the following error: *parsing time "November 25, 2016" as "September 9, 2016": cannot parse "November 25, 2016" as "September 9,* "

I assume the Parse function cannot parse every layout, but I'm curios what's the usual way of reading dates and parse them into time objects.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your layout date is wrong. Should be `"January 2, 2006"`. As the specs say:

> The layout defines the format by showing how the reference time,
>   defined to be `Mon Jan 2 15:04:05 -0700 MST 2006` would be interpreted
>   if it were the value

Answer (score 5):

The layout, if you're not using one of the pre-included constant layout that comes with the time module, must be formed from the exact timestamp `Mon Jan 2 15:04:05 -0700 MST 2006`. Notice that each element of it is unique, so each numeric identifier can be automatically parsed. it's basically 1 (month), 2 (day), 3 (hour), 4 (minute), 5 (second), 6 (year), 7 (time zone) etc.

It's better to use one of the pre-defined standard layouts that are included with the library:

```
const (
        ANSIC       = "Mon Jan _2 15:04:05 2006"
        UnixDate    = "Mon Jan _2 15:04:05 MST 2006"
        RubyDate    = "Mon Jan 02 15:04:05 -0700 2006"
        RFC822      = "02 Jan 06 15:04 MST"
        RFC822Z     = "02 Jan 06 15:04 -0700" // RFC822 with numeric zone
        RFC850      = "Monday, 02-Jan-06 15:04:05 MST"
        RFC1123     = "Mon, 02 Jan 2006 15:04:05 MST"
        RFC1123Z    = "Mon, 02 Jan 2006 15:04:05 -0700" // RFC1123 with numeric zone
        RFC3339     = "2006-01-02T15:04:05Z07:00"
        RFC3339Nano = "2006-01-02T15:04:05.999999999Z07:00"
        Kitchen     = "3:04PM"
        // Handy time stamps.
        Stamp      = "Jan _2 15:04:05"
        StampMilli = "Jan _2 15:04:05.000"
        StampMicro = "Jan _2 15:04:05.000000"
        StampNano  = "Jan _2 15:04:05.000000000"
)
```

Answer (score 1):

You should treat it as an example which you provide to `time.Provide`. And it should be of concrete value described in the documentation.

> Parse parses a formatted string and returns the time value it represents. The layout defines the format by showing how the reference time, defined to be
>
> Mon Jan 2 15:04:05 -0700 MST 2006

[A playground with correct variant.](https://play.golang.org/p/aY5g2LVyuz)